# error in using open() in CUDA C

Tags: c, cuda, system-calls

I try to open a file in CUDA C

```
fd = open("stats.txt", O_CREAT)
```

The open() is supposed to run in host side, compilation passed but there was a link error.

```
In function `open':
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/fcntl2.h:45: undefined reference to `__open_too_many_args'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am surprise that searching on Google didn't present anything close. Does anyone has any hints how to solve this problem? Thanks a lot!

---

Yes, I actually used 0644, sorry for the typo. I simplified the program as the following and still get the link error.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
  int fd;
  if((fd = open("stats.txt",O_CREAT|O_RDWR, 0644)) == -1) { printf("Can't open stats.txt.\n"); }
  else printf("stats.txt opened.\n");
  return 0;
}

nvcc  -c -arch sm_20 --keep --compiler-options -fno-strict-aliasing  -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -I../NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/common/inc/ -I../../libcuda -L../NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/lib -lcutil -DUNIX -O3 try.cu -o try

try.cu(13): warning: variable "fd" was set but never used

try.cu(13): warning: variable "fd" was set but never used

g++  -g -c try.cu.cpp -o try.cu_o

g++  -Wall -O3 try.cu_o -o try -L../libcuda -lcuda -L/home/NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/lib -static -static-libgcc   -L/usr/lib64 -lcutil_x86_64 -lm -lc

try.cu_o: In function `open':
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/fcntl2.h:45: undefined reference to `__open_too_many_args'
```

Due to some dependency, I have to use older nvcc

```
nvcc: NVIDIA (R) Cuda compiler driver
Copyright (c) 2005-2010 NVIDIA Corporation
Built on Wed_Nov__3_16:16:57_PDT_2010
Cuda compilation tools, release 3.2, V0.2.1221
```

g++ is 4.6.3. Thanks.

Comment: The mode is best represented in octal, not hexadecimal, since the bits are in groups of 3. For read/write by owner and read-only by group and others, use `0644`.

Comment: Using CUDA 6.5, on Fedora 20, I can compile/link this without issue.  Can you provide a specific, complete code (with all include headers, etc.) as well as the CUDA version and OS you are using?  [Here](http://pastebin.com/BCVKB5cg) is my example.  Please provide an example like it that fails.

Comment: Your sequence of compile commands is not logical.  This is not how you build a cuda program.  The `--keep` option is not necessary, and using one of the intermediate files it retains, and then expecting something sensible from that, is, well, not sensible.  And by the way, CUDA 3.2 is **very** old.

Comment: The code you have shown should compile just fine if you using the following compile command: `nvcc  -arch sm_20 --compiler-options -fno-strict-aliasing  -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -I../NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/common/inc/ -I../../libcuda -L../NVIDIA_GPU_Computing_SDK/C/lib -DUNIX -O3 try.cu -o try`

Answer (score 6):

The `open()` functions come in 2 variants.

```
int open(const char *pathname, int flags);
int open(const char *pathname, int flags, mode_t mode);
```

If you specify the `O_CREAT` flag, you *must* also specify the `mode` argument (the file permission bits).

So your code should be e.g.

```
fd = open("stats.txt", O_CREAT, 0644)
```

The linker error for `__open_too_many_args` just a way to fail the compilation/linking done by recent  glibc headers by using gcc specific trickery to catch the case where you pass `O_CREAT` to `open()`, but fail to provide the 3. mode argument.

Comment: Strictly speaking, the `open` function is variadic, like `printf`. The declaration ([according to POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/open.html)) is `int open(const char *path, int oflag, ...);`, so ordinarily incorrect calls that pass or don't pass the third argument would not be diagnosed by the compiler. It's interesting that the OP's compiler prints that error message, but I wonder whether adding the required 3rd argument would avoid it. If not, it could be an installation error.

Comment: Yes - the op should be getting an error of `__open_missing_mode`, not `__open_too_many_args` - so it could be a problem with cuda

Comment: Actually, I wouldn't expect either error. If the declaration of `open` matches the standard one, the call `open("stats.txt, O_CREAT)` is legal, though it might not behave correctly.  The compiler and/or linker must be doing something special (beyond what's defined by the C and POSIX standards) to diagnose the incorrect number of arguments. But I don't know much about CUDA; are those particular errors something specific to it?

Comment: The fcntl.h header (or rather bits/fcntl2.h) of glibc uses gcc specific features to catch just this case, open() is defined as an inline vararg function, and it inquires the number of parameters with __builtin_va_arg_pack_len())

Comment: I also tried creating the file first, then pass only O_RDWR, again, with or without 0644, the linking failed with the same reason. Why is there are "undefined reference to" a function, it should already be defined in fcntl2.

Comment: So this points out a real problem in the OP's original code, but it doesn't solve the link error. On my own x86_64 Linux Mint system, I see what appears to be some gcc-specific code using `__open_too_many_args and `__open_missing_mode`, apparently to catch this kind of error, but I don't get a link error on incorrect calls.

Comment: @KeithThompson It appears it's only available when using fortify (i.e. compile with  -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -O2) Anyway, I'll delete the answer as the problem is probably elsewhere and related to cuda

Comment: When I use that, I get "error: call to ‘__open_missing_mode’ declared with attribute error: open with O_CREAT in second argument needs 3 arguments". I wouldn't necessarily delete this answer; it's good information and the comments are informative.

Answer (score 0):

nvcc (in version 3.2) creates the intermediate file (*.cu.cpp) where the definitions of `__open_missing_mode` and `__open_too_many_args` bypass the gcc-intrinsic `__errordecl` used in fcntl2.h. Thus, the code

```
__errordecl (__open_too_many_args,
        "open can be called either with 2 or 3 arguments, not more");
__errordecl (__open_missing_mode,
        "open with O_CREAT in second argument needs 3 arguments");
```

that appears in fcntl2.h, becomes

```
# 36 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/fcntl2.h" 3
extern "C" void __open_too_many_args();
# 38 "/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/fcntl2.h" 3
extern "C" void __open_missing_mode();
```

in the intermediate (.cu.cpp) file. In effect, the .cu_o file has undefined references. I could not find a better fix than to comment out the extern statements and subsequent use of `__open_missing_mode` and `__open_too_many_args` in the intermediate file, which then allows correctly linking with the .cu_o file.

In my case, using nvcc v3.2 is a requirement (for hardware simulation), so I did not check other versions of nvcc.